# Spotify Music search intent

Tags: android, android-intent, spotify

I am working on an Android app that launches Spotify and triggers a search (i.e. for "Michael Jackson - Smooth Criminal"). That works pretty well.
Unfortunately there is a new app called [Spotify Music](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spotify.music&hl=en). All my attempts to trigger a search within that new app failed .. do you have any idea how to achieve that?

Here are the intents that worked for the older versions of Spotify:

```
/**
     * 
     */
    private void viewOnSpotify() {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.setAction(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
                    "com.spotify.mobile.android.ui",
                    "com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.Launcher"));
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "Michael Jackson - Smooth Criminal");
            this.startActivity(intent);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.viewOnSpotifyFallback();
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private void viewOnSpotifyFallback() {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.setAction(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
                    "com.spotify.mobile.android.ui",
                    "com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.activity.MainActivity"));
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "Michael Jackson - Smooth Criminal");
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: When you asked Spotify how to integrate with their Android app, what did they tell you?

Comment: they told me to ask on StackOverflow because thats the best way to get in touch with their developers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted, there is a new "Spotify Music" app, which has a different package name than the previous (and deprecated) app. The new package name is `com.spotify.music`, so your intent code should look like this:

```
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
        "com.spotify.music",
        "com.spotify.music.MainActivity"));
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I will give it a try and report the results as soon as possible

Comment: @Markus awesome, glad to hear it!

Comment: Anyway to get this to play as well as open the search? I thought INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH was supposed to play as well?